How to set TLS version of TWebBrowser?
I used TWebBrowser in my application and it has an error in some addresses, like Google Tag Manager (AErrorUrl 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-xxxxx'). I found the problem is the browser cannot communicate with TLS 1.2 and greater. How can I change the TLS version in TWebBrowser? for example, to set it to TLS 1.2?

Which version of Delphi are you using? Are you using the VCL or FMX flavor of TWebBrowser? There have been different incarnations of TWebBrowser over the years. But typically TWebBrowser is a wrapper for an OS provided browser, and so uses the OS's TLS settings. Which OS are you running your app on, and does that OS have TLS 1.2 enabled in its system settings?

@RemyLebeau I used VCL in Delphi 12 Update 1 and Tested on Windows 11 and 7, yes, TLS1.2 is Enabled on settings, this problem has happened on hundreds of my users.

You can simply test this error, only add TWebBrowser to form and navigate to page which have Google Tag Manager track script witch can not download this script from address is in question.

What exactly makes you think TLS is the problem? What did you do to diagnose that? In any case, the VCL TWebBrowser is old, have you tried the newer TEdgeBrowser yet? Using TEdgeBrowser Component and Changes to the TWebBrowser Component

@RemyLebeau This error show when navigate, not changed any things and this problem start from two week ago on all users. "Turn on TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1, and TLS 1.2 in Advanced settings and try connecting to https://ads.mydomain.com again. If this error persists, contact your site administrator."
